# How to hook up handlers to existing HTML with Angular

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I am writing an Angular application that fetches and displays some existing HTML documents.

I use a service to fetch large preexisting documents (from a third party) and display them in a panel (using `innerHtml` binding).

```html
<div class='legal-doc-panel' [innerHtml]='doc'></div>
```

This works as expected.

The application I am writing augments the existing documents with additional information.

I would like to detect when a user hovers over/clicks various elements in the "imported" HTML and display additional content in a separate panel.

Essentially I would like to hook the mouse handlers for some elements that I bring into the page (via `innerHtml`) and respond to them.

What is the recommended/cleanest way to do this ?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not have aware of whatever you are putting into innerHtml. But you can listen to events at the host element which Angular has aware of:

```
<div class='legal-doc-panel' [innerHtml]='doc' (myEvent)="onMyEvent()"></div>
```

And in your inner html you can emit events like you would do on components with EventEmitter. Something like this maybe:

```
var event = new CustomEvent("myEvent", {
    someData: 'foo'
});

hostElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Anyway i would suggest that the cleanest solution is not to use innerHtml at all. Instead your server could give you JSON and you build the html with Angular.

If you have no control about the inserted html you can use vanilla JavaScript inside your component.ts after you inserted your innerHtml. Just search for the elements inside of your div and use addEventListener() as you would do with regular JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Mick. I don't think that your suggestion would help achieve what I am trying to do. I do not need to trigger an custom event. I just need to detect browser events (i.e. click events) over specific html elements from a piece of html that I do NOT control (an html I imported on my page).  Also, I do not control the content displayed in the innerHtml, it is a third party server that provides snippets of legal documents as HTML which I augment with the information from my own server (which returns JSON data).

Comment: You can only listen to events on your host. Only chance is outside of Angular to hook into the events of your innerHtml and emit them to the host like you would do with components like i described above.

Comment: If you know the content you can use native JavaScript of course. After you put in the innerHtml you can search the elements and listen to events from within your component. Just be sure not to use addEventListener() on every onChange. I edited my answer to add this.

Comment: Hello @Mick. The way I am doing it at the moment (which works but I was looking for a more 'angular' way to do it) is to hook up the click event of my 'host' div and intercept all the clicks in the 'hosted' html there. Then I find out the clicked element by looking in the `target` property of the event. I was hoping that there is a better way.  As I said in the previous comment I do not need any custom event... the events I'm interested in are mouse events, I was just hoping that there is a nicer way to somehow intercept them.